# R: top-bottom forecasting for groups using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, forecast

I found this [excellent `sweep` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW01_Forecasting_Time_Series_Groups.html) authored by @Matt Dancho, but I want to make sure that the process follows a top-bottom approach, i.e.  that the forecast of subgroups would equal to the forecast of total.

To use Matt's example, if `bike_sales_monthly` and `monthly_qty_by_cat2` tables were forecasts (not actuals), I want to makes sure that the summed `monthly_qty_by_cat2$total.qty` to year and month level will equal `bike_sales_monthly$total.qty`.

This is definitely supported in `hts` package but I can't use it easily with `tidyverse` and more importantly, hts/gts models don't give you forecast confidence intervals.